# Python 2.7.5 installing issue

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I tried to install Python 2.7.5-64 bit in my system. I downloaded the python-2.7.5.amd64.msi from python.org website.

I am facing the following issue while tried installing it.

1. When clicked on the msi file. there is a window appears saying Change/Repair/Remove

Link to image: http://s22.postimg.org/cw92xphf5/image.jpg

2. When I chose any option suddenly a window comes saying "Special Thanks to ...." and then Finish option comes

Link to image: http://s7.postimg.org/72rtx8si3/image.jpg

Comment: Following window appears...

Comment: Check that it is not already installed via the Control Panel. If it's installed, use it! If not then there is a deeper issue with the installer believing it is installed.

Comment: Sorry I can't upload image

Comment: Even after uninstalling from Control Panel, the problem is same. When I chose Repair, it again starts appearing in Control Panel.

Comment: Does `C:\Python27` exist? Can you edit your question and include a link to screen shot of the window after the repair screen?

Comment: Are you administrator?

Comment: Yes . I am the administrator

Comment: I am facing this issue for installing any versions of Python

Comment: Select the option remove, and then install again.

Comment: I tried that. But nothing is happening. Always the 2nd image as shown above appears.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer obviously thinks that that version of python is installed.
Try:

- Removing everything to do with python in the control panel.(or python uninstaller in python dir?)
- Re-download the installer and try again.
  If this fails, I suggest you ask the python team or windows for help, as it is an error.